# Delete selected comments of a particular node?

Tags: 7

Is there any module in Drupal 7 for deleting *selected comments* at one go for a particular node?

Comment: There will be another tab with content in admin  section where all the content and at url admin/content/comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [Views Bulk Operation](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module. Follow the steps:

1. Install Views and Views Bulk Operation modules and enable these modules.
2. Create a View of Type **"Comment"**.
3. Change the Views Format *show* from **'Comment'** to **'Fields'** under Format section.
4. Change the Views *Format* from **'Unformatted list'** to **'Table'**.
5. Add **Bulk Operation:Comment, Comment:Title and Content:title** fields under Fields section.
6. In step 5 When you chose **Bulk Operation: Comment** select **Delete Item** under *SELECTED BULK OPERATIONS* setting.
7. Add **Content: Title** filter criteria and expose this filter So that you can filter comments of a particular node.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks:) @MutantMahesh. I just needed something like that.